# SimpleXMLElement Add Child Closure

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to create a simple XML document but I'm having difficulty grouping the children appropriately. My XML should look like this:

```
<news>
    <abc>
        <content>test</content>
    </abc>
    <abc>
        <content2>test2</content2>
    </abc>
</news>
```

I'm using the following code:

```
$newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<news></news>");
$news = $newsXML->addChild('abc');
$news->addChild('content','test');
$news->addChild('content2','test2');
echo $newsXML->asXML();
```

and getting this:

```
<news>
    <abc>
        <content>test</content>
        <content2>test2</content2>
    </abc>
</news>
```

How do I separate the children?

Comment: `My XML should look like this` ... but that's not valid XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want 2 `abc` child tags, you have to create 2 not 1

```
$newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<news></news>");
$news1 = $newsXML->addChild('abc');
$news1->addChild('content','test');
$news2 = $newsXML->addChild('abc');
$news2->addChild('content2','test2');
echo $newsXML->asXML();
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Spot on.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think to use addChild() for the same value more than once.

Comment: Probably because you understood at some level that it's a bad design having multiple children with the same name at the same level.